# Android WebView smooth scroll to anchor

Tags: android-webview, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I have a WebView with a number of anchors like this:

```
<a name='some_id'></a>
```

I am able to jump to the anchors using something like:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
    "window.location.hash='#" + hash + "';" +
"})()");
```

But is it possible to smoothly scroll to the anchors somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this would require a bit of effort on your end:

1. Instead of performing a fragment navigation, you'd need to [determine the position of the anchor element on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element). You'd need to use [addJavaScriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript) to convey this back to the Java side, don't forget to convert the CSS pixels you get from JS to physical pixels by multiplying by `webview.getScale()`.
2. Use an [OverScroller](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html) to drive the animation to the desired scroll offset.